# Conversion of character

Tags: c

What am I missing here? I want to convert the letters input by a user into corresponding integers in if statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      int i=0, j=0;
      int array[1000];


      printf("Input letters to convert into integers: ");
      do {
          scanf("%d", array[i]);
          i++;
      } while(array[i+1] != '\n');


     for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if (array[j] == 'A')
          printf("2 1 ");
        else if (array[j] == 'B')
          printf("2 2 ");
        //and so on...
```

Comment: For `Z` it will be `2 26`?

Comment: @coderredoc it's actually the keypad number and its keypress, sorry for not clarifying. Z would be 9 4

Comment: and what is error you are getting?

Comment: `scanf("%d", array[i]);`->`scanf("%d", &array[i]);` Also use `char` array and `%c` format specifier.

Comment: BTW in the while, add also a `&& i<1000`

Comment: @yajiv It should print 2 1 2 2 when I type AB but it only prints 2 2

Comment: `array[i+1] != '\n'` you are no testing what you think as scanf("%d", array[i])` wait for integer input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `int` array here a simple `char` array would do. And you can simply get all those characters in all at once using `%s` format specifier.

```
char array[1000];
if( 1 != scanf("%999s",array) ){
   fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
size_t len = strlen(array);
for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
   if( array[i] == 'A' ){
      ...
   } 
   else if( .. ){

   }
}
```

In case you need to get white space - `scanf` with `%s` format specifier won't be of help. Use `fgets` then.

```
char array[1000];
if( !fgets(array, 1000, stdin) ){
   fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
array[strcspn(array, "\n")] = 0;
size_t len = strlen(array);
for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
   if( array[i] == 'A' ){
      ...
   } 
   else if( .. ){

   }
}
```

Even better would be to use simply a switch case statement. That would save you from writing `26` `if -else` statement.

Also another point - instead of hard coding data in disguise of `if-else` just keep it stored in an array and then use it accordingly.

To explain the earlier problem - you have used the `scanf` wrong way - it would be `scanf("%d",&array[i]);` or `scanf("%d",array+i)`. It is the address of the variable not the variable value that is expected by `scanf`.

Not only that your code has potential problem of accessing array index out of bound - which is undefined behavior. (Consider when `i=999` you are accessing the `1000`th index). And you are comparing with uninitialized values - which is again a wrong way to go about.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! But I'm having issues with printing the space, ' ', that should print 1 1, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: @Jay.: To include white space you can simply go for `fgets` (There is a way to do the same with `scanf`).

Comment: @coderredoc "There is a way to do the same with `scanf`".  Yes but I bet 99% of attempts to do so fail to do so correctly.   `fgets()` is much easier to get right and even that has obscure holes.

Comment: @chux.: True. I admit that. I can't deny. Using `scanset` and then not understanding its behavior on many cases is pretty common. `fgets` is much cleaner to use.